# How to update mysql from 5.1 to 5.5

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, apt-get

I have a ubuntu server details are given below

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=natty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.04"
```

I want to upgrade from mysql 5.1 to 5.5 when Uninstall mysql and run this command it again install the same version of mysql server.

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

How do i install a mysql 5.5 server using the package manager and why is that apt-get doesnt install the latest version of mysql server  available and it there a way to install a specific version of mysql server

Comment: You probably want search [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), and, if not already covered there, ask there. ([Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) is part of the StackExchange network)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See **[Upgrading from MySQL 5.1 to 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html)**. 
Don't forget to backup your data before installing.

Comment: I have read it. But i was not able to understand much from it

Comment: Follow the instructions one by one from there

Comment: Y is that apt-get doesnt install the latest version of mysql server or is there a way to install a specific version of mysql server

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20190808070000/https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html